# Migrating a header file to a config file

Tags: c++

I currently have a header file with more than 20 defines in it. These defines set the properties of various objects. Now I must move these defines to a config file so that I do not have to rebuild the entire project when one of these values changes. I am currently thinking of having a static class whose static properties are set from reading from a config text file. Is there a better way to go? I know that I will have to write a whole text parser that will check for key values in the text files and then populate values. Are there any other ways? Suggestions for retrieving map value pairs?

Comment: Use a library to build, export and import those files in a common format like JSON or CSV.

Comment: A parser sounds like overkill, if you know at compile-time what values must be set. And why have a static class as middleman between the config file and the values?

Comment: You can save your configuration as a structured binary data file.

Comment: You don't need to write a parser, just use an existing one for JSON or YAML or .ini, or anthing else.

Comment: It depends on how flexible you need. If such properties are relatively constant and determined at compile time, you can even use precompiler variables and a understandable makefile. If you use them in runtime and only edit by you, you can define a struct, serialize it to file and deserialize when program starts. If you want pretty format, you need a ini parser, JSON parser or any human-readable text parser.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur could you explain your answer in a little more detail. How am i suppose to export a header file ?

Comment: I recommend checking out [`boost::program_options`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/program_options.html) at this juncture.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, an ini file and GetPrivateProfileString is quick and dirty.

Answer (score 2):

If you  are just trying to speed up builds by minimizing re-compiles, you don't need to write your own parser.  You can just write the configuration in C++.

Put the parameter declarations in an include file.

```
/* config.hpp */
class config
   {
public:
   static const int PARAM1;
   static const std::string PARAM2;
   static const double PARAM3;
   };
```

Edit and recompile the following C++ file when the configuration needs to change.

```
/* config.cpp */
const int config::PARAM1 = 1234;
const std::string config::PARAM2 = "hello";
const double config::PARAM3 = sin(M_PI/4);
```

Comment: The point of me migrating to a config file is to avoid recompiling files. The exe just reads from a config file

Comment: @MistyD: My solution will enable you to avoid recompiling all of the dependent files.  It will only take an instant to recompile 'config.cpp'.  If you have a huge project and you are actually trying to avoid both compiling *and* linking, then things git a bit more complicated.

Comment: Its not about recompiling its about an exe independant of the cpp file

Comment: @MistyD: Your question states that it *is* about recompiling: "so that I do not have to rebuild the entire project".

Comment: Yeah sorry about that another benefit I would like is having an exe to read from a text file. Sorry if i didnt make it clear.Though I really like you input